# Any way to get smaller chunk of raster grid from big `netCDF` file in R?

Tags: raster, r, netcdf

I have climate data in big `netCDF` file which covers 60 years time span climate data observation ([please take a look into this link](https://www.ecad.eu/download/ensembles/download.php)). However, I want to subset this climate data for only recent 20 years while discarding the time period that I don't want to use. I used `raster` package to read `netCDF` file in R, but to get a smaller chunk of raster grid from original `netCDF` file is unknown to me.

**goal**:

I want to subset or get a smaller chunk of raster grid (only 20 years' period climate data observation) from big `netCDF` file (it covers 60 year's climate data).

Is there any efficient fast way to get this done in R?

Comment: Subset by time first, then crop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key components were already addressed by [AF7](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/40117/af7) so this may not add much value, but I would suggest `raster::brick()` to enable `getZ()` function (as `brick()` keeps `@z` slot).

(I downloaded [0.44deg_tg](https://www.ecad.eu/download/ensembles/data/Grid_0.44deg_rot/tg_0.44deg_rot_v17.0.nc.gz) dataset (tg_0.44deg_rot_v17.0.nc)... not sure if this is you are after).

```
# Libraries {raster} and {ncdf4}
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
# read into R by raster::brick()
(tg <- brick("C:\\tg_0.44deg_rot_v17.0.nc"))
str(tg)

# Find the record of start and end dates
tg_date <- getZ(tg)            # extract Date information
grep("1998-01-01", tg_date)    # record [17533] corresponds to "1998-01-01"
grep("2017-12-31", tg_date)    # as above [24837] - end date

# Subset by date range. Then recover Date field, which was dropped during subsetting
# tg_20y is tg variable for 20 years
tg_20y <- subset(tg, 17533:24837)          # subset 1998-2017
tg_20y@z$Date <- tg@z$Date[17533:24837]    # put $Date back into @z slot
```

Comment: You can get tricky with the date classes eg., to query specific months you can use: grep( paste(c("May',"June"), collapse = "|") , months(tg_date))  or equivalently: which( months(tg_date) %in% c("May","June")) and even just subset the object directly: tg.sub <- tg[[which( months(tg_date) %in% c("May","June"))]]

Comment: @Jerry Thanks. Just a tiny dash, but I'm glad if it helped.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans Thanks for the tip, it works like a charm and gives stylish file. I haven't gone further yet but it would be very useful to analyze changes across these years.

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at the [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/raster.pdf) of the `raster` package and the package [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/vignettes/Raster.pdf), which cover this topic.
You want open the whole file using `stack()` or `brick()`, then subset to the layers you want using the `[[` operator, like this:

```
library(raster)
filename = "some_file.nc"
s = stack(filename, varname="varname")
s # take a look
s_subset = s[[layer_numbers]]
```

If you need to subset to specific timestamps easily, you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46001573/convert-a-netcdf-time-variable-to-an-r-date-object).

As for efficiency and speed, this is as fast as it can be. However, how fast it is really depends on the chunking of the netCDF file.